# Convert numbers to alphabets

Tags: linux, bash

I wanted to convert the numbers from 1 to 26 to Latin alpgabet {a-z}. 1 correspnds to "a", and 2 to "b" and 26 to "z"

The following command only works for single digit numbers:

```
echo "$i" | tr 123456789 abcdefghi
```

for instance

```
echo "1" | tr 0123456789 abcdefghi
```

will produce "a"

How could you do it for :

```
echo "$i" | tr 01234567891011121314151617181920212223 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Comment: OK. So what is the expected output for 11? `aa` or `k`?

Comment: I wanted to have k not "kk"

Comment: `kk` was not an option.

Comment: Choroba that is correct. What is your suggestion then ?

Answer (score 1):

`tr` only translates from one character to exactly one other character.  You need to produce an expression via `awk` instead:

```
echo "$i" | awk 'chr($1+48)' # This only handles the numbers
echo "$i" | awk 'chr($1+87)' # This only handles lowercase
```

But note that this will not account for the specific pattern (0-9a-z) that you are looking for.  You'll need to do more to separate the characters based on their ordinal ASCII value if you want it in a single expression.

Comment: "chr" is not a function in awk ?!

Comment: @Yacob This is a result of incomplete copy/paste.

Answer (score -3):

Hexadecimals can be echoed as easy as `-e` option

```
echo -e "\x41\x42\x43"
```

prints

```
ABC
```

How do you separate your integers? Do you understand that 11 can be interpreted as 11 or as 1,1?